# Developing locally interacting Composer packages for PHP

Tags: composer-php

I'm developing multiple packages for Composer (PHP) and some are libraries and other projects. All of these are using others, so the graph is a little bit complex.

So, I developed a test project for these libraries and I would test it locally, **instead for pushing untested code**.
As requirements of this project and library, I could use version (remote tag through packagist) and dev-main or * (local path).
My test project is providing 2 composer.json, one for public usage with remote packages and one for development with local packages.

To use local package, I am doing

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../*",
        "options": {
            "symlink": false
        }
    }
],
```

It seems working fine, except that my libraries are requiring mutually and their own composer.json can not be changed because of the possibility of online usage. And instead of the specified version constraint, I would it to use the local version (probably already included by root package).
AS some are using other external online packages, I think, I can not use the command option -*-root-reqs*

The common error is

> Problem 9
> - Root composer.json requires maintainer/library-1 * -> satisfiable by maintainer/library-1[dev-main].
> - maintainer/library-1 dev-main requires maintainer/library-2 1.* -> satisfiable by maintainer/library-2[v1.0.0, ..., v1.8.4] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but
> maintainer/library-2[dev-main] from path repo (../*) has higher
> repository priority. The packages from the higher priority repository
> do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. That
> repository is canonical so the lower priority repo's packages are not
> installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.

Ideas

1. Force composer to ignore constraint and use dev-main for all
2. Force composer to use already included packages and ignore new constraints
3. Use dev requirements to override requirements

**EDIT**
Some changes are refactoring in libraries, so some other libraries, and the test project too, should be updated to take these changes into account.

Comment: "instead for pushing untested code" - if crafting a local environment to test the code is that different, why not use a CI server like Jenkins or Gitlab to automatically test the code before merging it?

Comment: There are transverse developments.

Comment: Whatever you mean by "transverse developments": please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I mean simultaneous developments on several packages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **test locally** and **across multiple composer packages** that are developed in their own project directories, I'd recommend you to set up your test-system with a [composer repository of type `artifact`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact).

An artifact repository is a collection of tar- or zip-files and to have Composer support it, the PHP zip extension needs to be installed and enabled for the PHP version you're using to run `composer.phar` with.

You can create those archive files with [the `composer archive` command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#archive) or any other command that is producing standard zip- or tar-archives (e.g. `zip(1)`, `tar(1)`, `git-archive(1)`, ...).

This allows you to do what you call *"transverse developments"*, that result in multiple versions of the same package, without publishing any of them first.

This is similar to the [`path` repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) you already have but with the difference of now having multiple versions (composer.json configurations) per package, not only one, because you can build all the different versions' zip files and have all of them during testing.